# Regex to match only URLs with a tld

Tags: javascript, regex

I know there are endless regular expressions out their to validate URLs, but I've run into a problem with all that I've found. I need a regular expression that will match on all Http or Https urls, but not validate if the link doesn't have a tld and doesn't validate if it is missing a subdomain. It also needs to match the full url slug if possible.

The following are examples of urls that **should not** validate:

```
https://www
https://www.
https://www.exampledomain
```

Here's a couple examples of URLs that should validate:

```
https://www.axiamed.com
https://www.axiamed.com/independent-software-vendors/
```

I’ve been using the following regular expression...

```
((ftp|https?)://[-\w]+(\.\w[-\w]*)+|(?:[a-z0-9](?:[-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?: com\b|edu\b|biz\b|gov\b|in(?:t|fo)\b|mil\b|net\b|org\b|[a-z][a-z]\b))(\:\d+)?(/[^.!,?;"'<>()\[\]{}\s\x7F-\xFF]*(?:[.!,?]+[^.!,?;"'<>()\[\]{}\s\x7F-\xFF]+)*)?
```

...but it’s getting matches for the last of the 3 urls listed above that I don’t want matches for. Not sure where to go from here. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks to anyone willing to help!

Comment: Your regex is hopelessly incomplete. It evidently pre-dates the TLD explosion.

Comment: you could use a dummy `a` tag and get the protocol and path attributes from that. Are you open to such a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Hai this is an example javascript code  for your problem

```js
var result =/^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/|ftp:\/\/www\.|ftp:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/.test("https://www.axiamed.com/independent-software-vendors/");
if(result)
alert("url Matching");
else
alert("Url not matching")
```

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

How about?
    `/^(ftp|https?)\:\/{2}w{3}\.[a-z_A-Z]{1,}\.[a-z]{3}(\/(.){1,})?/g`

```js
var urls = [
    "https://www",
    "https://www.",
    "https://www.exampledomain",
    "https://www.axiamed.com",
    "https://www.axiamed.com/independent-software-vendors/"
]
var valids = urls.map((str) => {
  return str.match(/^(ftp|https?)\:\/{2}w{3}\.[a-z_A-Z]{1,}\.[a-z]{3}(\/(.){1,})?/g)
})
console.log(valids)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try whit this

> ^(http://www.|https://www.)?[a-z0-9]+([-.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(/.*)?$

```js
var a =[
"https://www.example.com",
"http://www.example.com",
"www.example.com",
"example.com",
"http://blog.example.com",
"http://www.example.com/product",
"http://www.example.com/products?id=1&page=2",
"http://www.example.com#up",
"https://www",
"https://www.",
"https://www.exampledomain",
"https://www.axiamed.com",
"https://www.axiamed.com/independent-software-vendors/",
];
a.forEach(function(url) {
   var result =/^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.)[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/.test(url);
if(result){


console.log(url+" TRUE");
}
else{

console.log(url+" FALSE")
}
});
```